# GAE Billing Aggregation for several instances in an account

Tags: google-app-engine, android-pay

I've got a simple question.

Now I'm trying to pay for 10 GAE instances of one account,
but I'm not sure whether there is a way to receive only one receipt for these instances per week.

Thanks for your kindness

Comment: you mean applications not instances

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible yet, there is an [open issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1999&q=billing&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) about it.